# Expression of odd and even functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f,g$ be respectively odd and even analytic functions. Then, it is true that there exist $F,G$ real analytic such that $f(x)=xF(x^2)$ and $g(x)=G(x^2)$. This easily follows by writing the functions in series. 
My question is: does it still holds if we assume $f$ and $g$ only $\mathcal{C}^1$ (with $F,G\in\mathcal{C}^1$, too)?
I suppose that this does not holds if $f$ and $g$ are only supposed to be continue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: And then I assume you also want $F$ and $G$ to be $\mathcal{C}^1$? (Since it's too much to ask that they be analytic.)

Comment: Yes, right. I edit my question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you require $F$ and $G$ to be also $\mathcal C^1$, then no. Consider $g(x) = |x|^\alpha$ for even case, and $f(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot |x|^\alpha$ for odd, where $2 > \alpha > 1$.

For example, for $g(x) = |x|^\alpha$ we have $g'(x) = |x|^{\alpha - 1}$ for $x \neq 0$, and by direct limit calculation we have $g'(0) = 0$, thus $g(x) \in \mathcal C^1$.

But we would have $G(x) = g(\sqrt{x}) = |x|^{\alpha / 2}$, which isn't $\mathcal C^1$, because $G'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: So the fact is that they exist but you loose regularity, right? And if I assume only continuity?

Comment: If you have only continuity, you can find continuous $G(x) = \sqrt{g(|x|)}$, but you not necessary can find continuous $F$, for example if $f(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot \sqrt{|x|}$. In general, I think if original function was $\mathcal C^n$, you can get $G$ to be in $\mathcal C^{\lfloor n / 2\rfloor}$ and $F$ in $\mathcal C^{\lfloor (n - 1) / 2\rfloor}$.